# Editext push down all content of layout

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi I'm trying to create `EditText` **multiline** but when I back to line all content of layout go down:

[image: Scrennshot]

manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
       /...
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:maxLength="80"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="so.not.Vaporwave"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textColorHint="#a9ffffff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/exmple"
    android:id="@+id/edtietxt" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set MAX height for the edit text so that it won't expand dynamically

> android:maxHeight="100dp"

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:maxLength="80"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="so.not.Vaporwave"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:maxHeight="100dp"
    android:textColorHint="#a9ffffff"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edtietxt" />
```